# How to develop a mobile version website, without changing it's domain name?

Tags: php, http, .htaccess, dns

I want to develop the mobile (also includes iphone,ipad,andriod) version of my original site. But I don't want to create another sub domain like www.m.mydomain.com, can i dynamically change the document root separately for mobile version and the existing one?
I have also noticed that, when I open facebook form iphone or any andriod mobile it opens with it's original domain name like http://www.facebook.com/ bt when i open it from any other mobile like nokia or samsung it comes with http://m.facebook.com/, what is the difference between this 2?

Comment: Do you want the same functionality, but different look and feel, or a completely different site altogether?

Comment: i want the same site with most of functionalities. in mobile version of my site i want to optimize(image,css,js) it to run smoothly in mobile.

Comment: You could look into Responsive web design. [This article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) might give you some insight.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to iPhone and Android deveices, a website needs very little adjustments because their web browsering capabilities are really good.

For other devices where the web browsing user experience is less satisfying, the site would dynamically switch them to an alternate and less "intense" version of the website.

As for the m.domain.com feature, this is just a subdomain of the domain.com website. Obviously, it represents a mobile version of the main site and will strip out things like flash and javascript basically anything which will be too much for a basic mobile browser.

The dynamic switching of browsers is done via code. There are ways of detecting what browser just requested your website. Based on the information returned you can then redirect to specific scripts which will handle the user requests from then on.

As an example, you can use this standard argument to check the browsers visiting your site:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate it by `User-Agent` property either on Apache level, or PHP level. Though that will not be guaranteed because UA can be spoofed. (But how many mobile users would do UA spoofing to pretend they're not mobile?)

Comment: `But how many mobile users would do UA spoofing to pretend they're not mobile?` Me ;) Sometimes mobile version works worste than normal-version on mobile-device ;(

Answer (score 1):

you could possibly use some solution:

create a specific mobile website and put it on folder/subdomain and redirect any user with mobile to that site, example: mydomain.com/m/ or m.mydomain.com

example on redirection:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php

or

you could use responsive webdesign technique, some framework already available for this
http://csswizardry.com/inuitcss/
http://www.columnal.com/
http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that high end mobile devices like iphone/android have enough support and functionality to support the original version of the website (zooming/javascript etc). Other devices are better served an basic website developed for mobile devices with a limited display and/or support.

You do want an special URL for your mobile website - as you'd like your mobile website to correctly appear in the mobile search of search engines.

Answer (score 0):

www is actually also a subdomain, but it is so often used, people do not usually realize it, Usually most browsers add it by default and this is why most servers have it enabled by default.

The case you pointed out is also of subdomains. The server check your HTTP request's user-agent and redirects you to the mobile subdomain appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a quick solution for you, but I highly recommend reading Ethan Marcotte's Responsive Web Design articles on [alistapart.org](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). He goes over the philosophy as well as the practical steps to make a site work well for different contexts - desktop browser to mobile device, etc. There are several articles on the site (just search for responsive web design you'll get several of his articles in your results.)